# Impersonation not working - Asp.Net core 3.1 application with Windows Authentication hosting in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, windows-authentication, blazor

I created a Blazor Server application (.Net core 3.1). The application uses Windows authentication. The application will need to access some Windows services like file sharing, and database with Integrated security etc. So it has the following impersonation code.

```
var identity = await IdentityProvider.GetIdentityAsync();

if (identity.IsAuthenticated && identity is WindowsIdentity wid)
{
    return WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(wid.AccessToken, () =>
    {
        Fun1(....); // Should be called using the authentication of logged in user
    });
```

The `Fun1()` should be called using the identity of the Windows users who are using the application, instead of the account which is used to running the website.

For example, the Identity of the application pool for my web site is `MyDomain\UserX`. And when a user `MyDomain\UserY` is using the website. I want the function `Fun1()` is impersonated under `MyDomain\UserY` instead of `MyDomain\UserX`.

I created a website on IIS, published the code, disabled anonymous authentication and enabled Windows Authentication. However, the function `Fun1()` is still called using the identity in the Application Pool? Should any settings in the Active directory be changed?

Comment: Similar scenario, similar code.
In a try-catch it return ACCESS_DENIED to me from IIS while on my machine works correctly.
Seems to use the correct identity though because WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name returns the correct one inside RunImpersonated.
Maybe it's related to this: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29935

Answer (score 2):

In order to access database using the logged in user's credentials (the user who is accessing your API and not site's app pool identity), you need to setup Kerberos constrained delegation. Pls refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/kerberos/kerberos-constrained-delegation-overview

[https://blogs.uw.edu/kool/2016/10/26/kerberos-delegation-in-active-directory/#:~:text=What%20is%20Kerberos%20Delegation%3F,tier%20is%20the%20web%20site](https://blogs.uw.edu/kool/2016/10/26/kerberos-delegation-in-active-directory/#:%7E:text=What%20is%20Kerberos%20Delegation%3F,tier%20is%20the%20web%20site).

this may not be helpful to you, as the question was asked long time ago. but may be useful if someone else is in the same situation.